# Read specific columns from a pinned arrow dataset using pin_read in R

Tags: r

I have a pinned dataframe of type 'arrow' that lives in RStudio Connect. If this were a regular feather file, I could load specific columns like this:

```
df <- read_feather(my_file, col_select = c(col1, col2))
```

Is there a way to do something similar with a pinned dataframe using `pin_read`? If not, are there other ways to query specific columns from a dataframe stored in RStudio Connect?

Comment: `pins` supports alternate formats, see https://pins.rstudio.com/articles/managing-custom-formats.html?q=arrow#upload-a-single-file. I don't know that it supports "lazy" querying of partial data, though, similar to `arrow::open_dataset`+`dplyr`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the *"I don't know that it supports"* part of my comment, seems you've confirmed that. The only way I know of to do lazy-querying like that with arrow/parquet is via their "Flight" API, see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Flight.html.

Comment: Deleted my last comment --- I was wrong! something like this is possible: `feather_file <- arrow::open_dataset(pin_download(b, name = "df"), format = "feather")` and then `data_subset <- feather_file %>% select(col1, col2) %>% collect()`

Comment: I believe that's still _downloading_ the whole file into a temporary local file before querying, but the good news is that you aren't loading all of the data into R's memory before doing that. Glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by pinning the dataset with `pin_upload_arrow()` rather than `pin_write(type="arrow")`. For example:

```
pin_upload_arrow(b, x = my_data, name = "my_data")

feather_file <- arrow::open_dataset(pin_download(b, name = "my_data"), format = "feather")

feather_file %>%
  select(col1, col2) %>%
  collect()
```